# Is hot reload supported for ASP.NET Core 6 Web API controllers?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, hot-reload

I don't know if this a supported feature or not. I used `dotnet new webapi` to test the concept. I am using the .NET 6 SDK. The generated code includes a `WeatherForecast` controller.

I cannot get hot reload working for the code in the controller. I run the app with `dotnet watch run`. I am told "Hot reload enabled".

I then edit the static string array for the weather summaries and save the changes. I am told:

> File changed: .\Controllers\WeatherForecastController.cs.'

and

> Hot reload of changes succeeded

But when I call the API at `https://localhost:7103/api/WeatherForecast`, the changed values are not used. I know that it is not a caching issue because it works the same if I switch browsers to see the results of the call after the changes.

I know my setup is fine because hot reloading works if I comment out the content of `program.cs` and replace it some calls to write lines to the console.

I checked  the article [Live Code Editing - Supported changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/supported-code-changes-csharp?view=vs-2022) but I do not see where it either should or should not work.

Comment: I'm using Hot Reload in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project just fine right now and changes to controller actions are applied just fine - are you using Visual Studio or just `dotnet` and a text-editor? My understanding is that Hot Reload basically requires the VS Debugger.

Comment: @Dai I was afraid of that. I read about Microsoft's plans to have it only available for VS. But I thought they had changed their mind. I'm using VsCode and planned on running "dotnet watch run" via a task in task.json.  For now I'm just running it from the command line. However, since hot reloading works fine for code outside the controller, I don't see why it shouldn't work for  the controller code.

Comment: Plus, I don't understand how choice of debugger even plays a part in hot reloading, since you can get it just using notepad to edit your source code -as Hanselman demonstrates in his video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4S3vPzawnoQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is YES.

My problem was that my code changes are apparently not changes that will be updated during a hot reload. As I said in my question, I edited the "static string array for the weather summaries".

On the page [Live Code Editing - Supported changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/supported-code-changes-csharp?view=vs-2022), it specifically states that one of the unsupported changes is to "Modify a static member after it has already been accessed by executing code". That is exactly what I was doing.

I make a different change (to the temperature calculation) and this change was implemented in the reloaded code.

But the problem had nothing to do with whether I was using Visual Studio, VsCode or just a text editor. Hot reloading still worked in all cases. In fact one of the things that I tried before finding the solution was to use VS2022. This also would not work if editing the static value.

However, you cannot use hot reload together with debugging in VsCode. You can use either feature, both not both together at the same time. This is only available in VS proper.